# Return all possible matches from an array of strings in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, forms

If, for example, i have an array :

```
$random = array("Woodpecker","Pecking","Kayaking");
```

Using HTML Forms, how can I get all possible matches of an input string.

For example if the input is 'Peck', i should get the output as `Woodpecker` and `Pecking`. Case insensitive.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far. Can't really tell if you've actually put any effort in yourself.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a "please code for me" platform. It's supposed to be a knowledge base, and what you're asking has been covered in countless answers to questions about regex. This tells me that yes, you haven't actually researched prior to asking a question, which is common courtesy here. Or at least supposed to be.

Comment: I suggest you read http://stackoverflow.com/help. Seeing as how you're a fairly new user, I'd seriously advise you to understand that this isn't a forum and you should behave accordingly.

Comment: If you'd read up, you could tell that I have no rights to delete any other comments than mine, meaning somebody else deleted your demeaning comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use loop to achieve this

```
<?php
$random = array("Woodpecker","Pecking","Kayaking");
foreach($random as $r)
{
    if(stripos($r,'peck') !== false)
        echo $r;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)  or  [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

```
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');
$key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
$key = array_search('red', $array);   // $key = 1;
```

Returns the key for needle if it is found in the array, FALSE
otherwise.

> If needle is found in haystack more than once, the first matching key
> is returned. To return the keys for all matching values, use
> array_keys() with the optional search_value parameter instead.

Comment: I had tried this, it did not work. Maybe something wrong that I did. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the array in a loop and use a function for matching strings.

[Iterate an array](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

[Match string with regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: Why not put it in an example rather than posting mere links?